# How can I recover a drive partition lost while uninstalling ubuntu

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning, data-recovery, partition-recovery

I have  a windows XP (SP2) desktop with 4 partitions C:14 GB ; D: 14 GB ;E: 55 GB; F:  55 GB;  (approximate size)

I had installed Ubuntu 10.04 by creating space for it using existing disk partition (as guided by the installer)

Two new partitions were created by the installer (one with 10GB and the other 500MB) which dint have any name like windows partitions (ex: c,d,e,f)
So, in the disk management I could see two unnamed partitions and 4 windows partitions (C,D,E,F) . Using Dual Boot i was able to use both windows and ubuntu

Recently i wanted to uninstall Ubuntu , so followed steps given in the internet.

As guided, I went to Disk Management, right clicked on the first unnamed partition(which belonged to Ubuntu) and clicked Delete Volume.

According to the tutorial only that particular partition should have been deleted.
But both my E and F drives disappeared including the other unnamed partition of Ubuntu. Now I can see only C drive (14gb) and D drive (14gb) and another partition which is seen as "120 GB free space" .

Also, I dont have a windows installation CD and I'm getting screen which shows GRUB rescue in the command prompt when I start my computer.

Just when I found out I lost 2 of the drives I shut down my computer.
When i started it again I got the GRUB rescue screen and have not been able to login since then.

And I see "120GB free space" instead of E and F drives in the Disk Management.

In MyComputer I can see only C and D drives.

I lost both E and F drives where I had stored most of my data. I badly want the data back .

Comment: I don't know why that happened though I haven't tried with ubuntu.easeus have a partition recovery program you can try http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery/

Comment: ok thank you. will i be able to recover all the data were present in those two drives

Comment: these programs will show you what you can recover, there are no guarantees, you may be surprised or disappointed, but if that one doesn't work there would no doubt be a few others you can try

Comment: if a partition or volume was deleted very quickly then I suppose so.. as it just deleted the link to it and kept everything in it. there are also data recovery programs which I think are for when you have a partition(and can even work after a quickformat though perhaps not after a format), but the partition recovery ones would get data too no doubt, and when you deleted a partition.

Comment: yes. the volume got deleted very quickly. within fraction of a second.Usually when we delete a large amount ,it takes more time. I hope I have the data still. I dint understand this part. "and can even work after a quickformat though perhaps not after a format"Could you please ellaborate

Comment: don't worry it's not relevant to you as you never formatted or quickformatted,  and you are using a partition recovery program , so just try the easeus partition recovery tool I mentioned.

Comment: Also you can try TestDisk

Answer (score 0):

You may have deleted an extended partition (something about logical volumes and more than 4 primary partitions). You can recover those partitions using some free or paid partition recovery software. I recommend [Active@ partition recovery](http://www.partition-recovery.com/). It's free AFAIK. Once the partition is recovered and mounted, you can use it like any other volume. You can even keep it, assuming that only the partition record was deleted.

EDIT: Yeah, it's freeware. Tried it myself.